# Zend Framework 2 - Gobal Variable that are accessible to controller/model that are initialize in local.php or global.php

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

Hello everyone please someone help me how to create a global variable in zend framework 2 to be use in table prefix that are accessible in controller and model.

Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: If you want the (merged) configuration, you can get it from a controller with `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('config')`. You shouldn't use global variables.

Comment: Thanks Sir. My problem on that part servicelocator was I cannot get the config on the model side. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding and implementing the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` to the model?

Answer (score 0):

In your config/database.local.php you can define which you want globally

```
<? 
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            //'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => function ($serviceManager) {
                $adapterFactory = new Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory();
                $adapter = $adapterFactory->createService($serviceManager);
                \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($adapter);
                return $adapter;
         }
        ),
    ),

    'db' => array(
        'driver'    => 'pdo',
        'dsn'       => 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
    ),
    'msg' => array(
        'add'    => 'Data Inserted Successfully',
        'edit'   => 'Data Updated Successfully',
        'delete' => 'Data Deleted Successfully',
    ),
);
?>
```

Controller File:
DemoController.php

```
<?php
  namespace Demo\Controller;
  use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    class DemoController extends AbstractActionController
    { 
       public function indexAction($cms_page_name='whyus')
        { 

            /*Call config file to fetch current cms page id-- fetch config file from database.local.php*/
            $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
            $all_msg = $config['msg'];
       }
    }
?>
```